# How do I avoid overlapping outlines?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I am creating a model of the [Nürburgring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BCrburgring) from an image using Bézier curves, I outlined the track, and used the array and curve modifiers to follow the path of the curve. I ended up with a result that looked like this:

[image]

I tried removing one of the lines from the traced track just to make sure that that wasn't the issue but ended up with much the same result. Any suggestions that could fix this?

Comment: Are both origins of curve and the object in same position? Do you have scale applied on both?

Comment: Please use descriptive titles

Comment: The origin of your bevel curve is the point that will lie on the path curve. The local Z axis of the bevel curve will point down the path curve.  You certainly want only a single curve as your path, not both sides of the track.

Comment: I have tried it with only a single curve and it makes no difference

Comment: In other words can someone explain how to fix this to me? Im pretty new to 3d modelling as a whole but know my way around a few things. I just dont understand what is making it make this weird shape. If there is a fix it probably needs to be lay out in steps or simple terms.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just now understood what Johan Apes was trying to say (don't ask why that took me so long). I changed the scale and position values to the same amount and I got it to go around the track. Thank you so much. When watching a video where a guy used this technique he said to do that but I just skipped over it thinking it was not necessary. Thanks for the help guys!